# Regular expression for string with apostrophes

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm trying to build regex which will filter form string all non-alphabetical characters, and if any string contains single quotes then I want to keep it as an exception to the rule.

So for example when I enter

```
car's34
```

as a result I want to get

```
car's
```

when I enter

```
*&* Lisa's car 0)*
```

I want to get

```
Lisa's
```

at the moment I use this:

```
string.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]", "")
```

however, it gives me only alphabets, and removed the desired single quotas.

Comment: Why don't you want `car` in 2nd string?

Comment: I edited the given examples

Comment: What is different about the "Lisa's" part and the "car" part of the 2nd example? Why keep "Lisa's" and not "car"?

Comment: @Luke I don't see any edit in that part.

Comment: Code colour in the given examples doesn't matter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will also remove apostrophes that are not "part if words":

```
string = string.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z' ]+|(?<=^|\\W)'|'(?=\\W|$)", "")
    .replaceAll(" +", " ").trim();
```

This first simply adds an apostrophe to the list of chars you want to keep, but uses look arounds to find apostrophes not within words, so

```
I'm a ' 123 & 'test'
```

would become

```
I'm a test
```

Note how the solitary apostrophe was removed, as well as the apostrophes wrapping `test`, but `I'm` was preserved.

---

The subsequent `replaceAll()` is to replace multiple spaces with a single space, which will result if there's a solitary apostrophe in the input. A further call to `trim()` was added in case it occurs at the end of the input.

Here's a test:

```
String string = "I'm a ' 123 & 'test'";
string = string.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z' ]+|(?<=^|\\W)'|'(?=\\W|$)", "").replaceAll(" +", " ").trim();
System.out.println(string);
```

Output:

```
I'm a test
```

Comment: I get `I'matest'`. What's going on?

Comment: Humm... Works with `I'm a ' 123 & 'test' ` => `I'm a    test `. But for `I'm a ' 123 & 'test'`, I get `I'm a    test'`.

Comment: @PaulVargas OK, fixed that too. Thanks for your patience and feedback. I really should test it huh...

Answer (score 5):

Isn't this working ?

`[^A-Za-z']`

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I can't believe that I have missed this! Thanks RP

Answer (score 2):

The obvious solution would be:

```
string.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z']", "")
```

I suspect you want something more.

Comment: What I wonder about is whether you want `12 'ape' 45` to become `'ape'` or `ape` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can try the regular expression:

```
[^\p{L}' ]
```

`\p{L}` denote the category of Unicode letters.

In ahother hand, you need to use a constant of Pattern for avoid recompiled the expression every time, something like that:

```
private static final Pattern REGEX_PATTERN = 
        Pattern.compile("[^\\p{L}' ]");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "*&* Lisa's car 0)*";

    System.out.println(
        REGEX_PATTERN.matcher(input).replaceAll("")
    );  // prints " Lisa's car "
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Bohemian has a good idea but word boundaries are called for instead of lookaround:

```
string.replaceAll("([^A-Za-z']|\B'|'\B)+", " ");
```

Comment: What is `\B` fragment?

Comment: \b matches a word boundary and \B matches a non-word boundary